# Making a shortcut keys for one shortcut key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

So, i switched to linux, but i am too used to microsoft shortcuts..

I got what replaces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> ([with Level3 key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780018/keyboard-all-ctrl-alt-1-0-combination-characters-not-working))..

So for better use, is there any way of Making <kbd>lvl3</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>?
   By that I mean like if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, it would act, like it would be <kbd>lvl3</kbd> +<kbd>1</kbd> (<kbd>1</kbd> is the example key in this case)

Thanks -Ras

Comment: This was possible [through the system settings once](http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/choosers/). Now I can only see solutions involving `xmodmap` or manual editing of keyboard layout files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9635/47852

Comment: i kinda got it: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ there file ee (estonian layout), next to it is normal, shift, level 3 and level 4? But how should you get 2 keys to one character or even 3 key combination and i think there is no option to change level 3 and if you even can, can you get it with 2 keys??